# Using Default Document with Forms Authentication

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net, default-document

I have a site hosted on IIS7 with a default document specified as **default.aspx**.  This works fine but my app uses Forms Authentication and I want to disable Anonymous Authentication completely.  When I do disable anonymous authentication for everything except the login page, everything works fine but the default document setting stops working.

With Anonymous authentication switched on if I visit **http://mysite** I get passed to **http://mysite/default.aspx** (which then redirects to the login page if the user hasn't already logged in)

If I disable anonymous authentication (leaving only forms based auth enabled) and I visit **http://mysite** I get a permission denied page from IIS.  Yet, if I visit **http://mysite/default.aspx** directly then the site works fine.

I just want to disable anonymous authentication and have **http://mysite** go to **http://mysite/default.aspx**.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a defaultDocument entry in the "system.webServer" element of the Web.Config?

```
<system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="Default.aspx" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Also, the if you want the default page to show up to those who have not yet been signed into the application, you must allow access with an authorization section like below:

(in system.web)

```
 <location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>        
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: This is what I've been doing, it works fine with anonymous authentication enabled.  But when I disable anonymous and only have forms auth enabled then **http://mysite** doesn't work (but *http://mysite/default.aspx* does work).  Turning off anonymous auth seems to break the default page section.

Comment: Have you added an authorization section to allow unauthenticated users access to the default page? Assuming you want the app to work like that?

Comment: Do you have an URL routing configured in the web.config?  That can mess with you default doc.